# How to include higher-level grouping into lmer model?

Tags: regression, r, mixed-model, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme

I have a panel dataset and my dependent variable is the logit-transformed share of farm workers on long-term contracts. I am particularly interested in the effect of pastoral focus in agriculture, represented by variable pastoral. The difficulty is two-fold. First,  the impact of this variable changes over time. Second, the data for this variable is only available at a higher level of grouping, called RC. To deal with the first issue, I use a mixed model:

```
model <- lmer(logitshare ~ pastoral + other variables + (pastoral | year), 
               data = mydata)
```

How can I deal with the second issue, i.e. include in the model the fact that pastoral is only available for RC?

Comment: What do you mean by a higher level of grouping? It would be important to determine how exactly the hierarchical structure works in this data before advising on a proper model.

Comment: Most of my data, including the dependent variable, is available for a small geographic area, a parish. However, I know the value of pastoral only for a much larger unit, a county. There are ~ 200 parishes per county.

Comment: Im also curious about what you mean by your DV being logit transformed. What is the reason for this transformation?

Comment: Originally it was a share of workers on long-term contracts. It is bounded between 0 and 1, and I transformed it to deal with this.

Comment: More clarification would be helpful. Is it the case that for each parish you have multiple years of data? And then you have an identifier for which RC the parish belonged to? How many RCs are in your data?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the case. I have data for 8000 parishes, grouped into 40 registration counties (RC), for 5 years. The issue is that one important variable, pastoral, is only available at a county level, and I have to use the county value for all parishes in it. Could you help?

Comment: Why not use logistic regression instead of logit transforming the response? The logistic regression is a model for logit(EY) while you have E(logit(Y)) so perhaps that's the motivation? If you can the number of workers (long-term & short-term) there are other modeling options too.

Comment: I have two reasons. First, I do not want to move to a more sophisticated approach, which means more assumptions, when a simpler model can work. Second, logistic regression is designed for binary variables, whilst my variable is continuous.

Comment: @Mikhail could you add some of the information from the comments into the question. Based on the body text I had the impression that your problem was that pastoral is a nested variable which is only 'available' for some measurements but not all.

Comment: What does it mean to you when a model 'works'? Do you just want to make a fit (which works easily), or do you also want to estimate the accuracy of the fit (which requires a sophisticated approach if you want it to work *and* also be realistic)?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Sorry if my description was not clear. Imagine a map, in which the country is divided into 40 counties, and each county is in turn divided into 200 parishes. My response variable and most predictors are for 8,000 parishes, over 5 years. The exception is 'pastoral', defined as a ratio of pastoral land to all cultivated land. It varied by parish but was only measured by county, so that I have to assume the same value for all parishes inside.

Comment: @Mikhail could you add that in the question. In the comments it might remain unnoticed by some readers.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus. My question is whether 'pastoral' had an impact. Now I can see that the coefficient is statistically significant, so the answer is 'yes'. However, I am concerned that this approach underestimates the variability of 'pastoral' which may effect this conclusion.

Comment: It's also relevant to know if pastoral varies over the five years for a given county. Does it?

Comment: Yes, it does. There are general trends that effect all counties, but these are subject to local variations too.

Comment: And as to the dependent, do you know the exact counts like 80 long-term out of a total of 200?  Or only the shares or percentages?

Comment: Yes, I have the counts.

Comment: That is better. I would then rather use a model for data binomial data instead of shares or percentages, for which you need the assumption that they normally distributed. Although with "large" counts the results could be very similar.

Comment: @BenP thank you for then I have two questions. First, what would be the dependent variable? Second, how will this resolve my issue with ‘pastoral’?

Comment: @BenP just because it is counts doesn't mean that it needs to be binomial distributed. The assumption behind that is that the contract of every worker, whether it is long term or short term, depends on an independent Bernoulli variable. It creates a strict assumption about the relationship between variance and mean. It is questionable whether that is right.

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus Agree, binomial came up first because there is a given total number n from which k are drawn. A choice for extra binomial variance could be considered e.g. random parish effect.

Comment: @Mikhail the pastoral variable can influence the dependant but that can only be estimated on the county level. Sextus Empiricus clearly explained that this is problematic.

Comment: @mikhail the dependent can consist of two variables, nr. of long and nr. of short term contracts for each parish and year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you should have time (`year`) at both levels like `pastorale` and the variable `RC` at the second level (clusters). Looking only on the question , something like the following code should yield the desired results.

```
model <- lmer(logitshare ~ pastoral + year + other variables + 
                           (pastoral + year | RC), data = mydata)
```

This model assumes that `pastoral` and `year` have random slopes and intercepts.

Regarding the comments, random intercept and slopes will account for differential effects across `RCi`.

You can test this by sequentially testing models.

```
# No random effects
mod0 <- lm(logitshare ~ pastoral + year + other variables, 
           data = mydata)

# Add random slopes
mod1 <- lmer(logitshare ~ pastoral + year + other variables + 
                           (1 | RC), data = mydata)

# Add random slopes for year
mod2 <- lmer(logitshare ~ pastoral + year + other variables + 
                           (1 + year | RC), data = mydata)

# Add random slopes for pastoral
mod3 <- lmer(logitshare ~ pastoral + year + other variables + 
                           (1 + pastoral + year | RC), data = mydata)
```

which you can test with

```
anova(mod0, mod1, mod2, mod3)
```

to see which one fits your data the best.

Comment: Thank you very much! What is the intuition behind this formula, how could adding a random slope at the RC level help?

Comment: How do you know that this is the desired result? There hasn't been any explanation about the underlying principles of the model. Why aren't the parishes added as random effect? Can we assume that the different years within the same parish are all independent? How is the application of ANOVA working put well without being sure about underlying assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

For the counts a few models might be compared. I assume that parishes are numbered from 1 to 8000 across all the counties.

1 Random county and parish effects.

```
model1 <- glmer(cbind(longt, shortt) ~ pastoral + year + (1|RC) + (1|parish), family=binomial, data=mydata)
```

2 Random year effects added. Maybe first only across counties, next also across parishes.

```
model2 <- glmer(cbind(longt, shortt) ~ pastoral + year + (1+year|RC) + (1+year|parish), family=binomial, data=mydata)
```

3 Random pastoral effect across counties. Only possible if pastoral changes over the years, given a county.

```
model3 <- glmer(cbind(longt, shortt) ~ pastoral + year + (1+year+pastoral|RC) + (1+year|parish), family=binomial, data=mydata)
```

These models assume that for a given parish/year observation, e.g. 80 longterm and 120 shortterm, all 200 workers have the same probability to be longterm. The models might improve by adding a random parish/year effect. E.g. for model1 you add:

```
  + (1|parish:year)
```

The exp() function of the fixed effects of pastoral and year are oddsratio's as usual for a logistic regression.

Comment: I typed on my mobile phone and this works terrible.

Comment: @mikhail I just realised that at the beginning of your question you said that the influence of pastoral varies over years. That could be modelled by adding the interaction of pastoral:year to the model. Forgot that.